# Artificially burden the CPU

Tags: linux, cpu-usage, benchmark

I'm looking for a command line application that will artificially burden the CPU.  It needs to be better than just a busy loop.  We're testing how the system holds up under heat stress and the CPU needs to generate as much heat as possible.

Comment: A similar question is on superuser.  [Linux program to artificially create CPU usage](http://superuser.com/questions/168524/linux-program-to-artificially-create-cpu-usage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Followed Zoredache's [link](https://superuser.com/questions/168524/linux-program-to-artificially-create-cpu-usage).  The question isn't really what I'm looking for.  However, the accepted answer mentioned [`cpuburn`](http://pages.sbcglobal.net/redelm/).

> *** WARNING ***
>   This program is designed to heavily load CPU chips.
>   Undercooled, overclocked or otherwise
>   weak systems may fail causing data
>   loss (filesystem corruption) and
>   possibly permanent damage to
>   electronic components. Nor will it
>   catch all flaws.
>   *** USE AT YOUR OWN RISK ***

With a warning like that it's got to be good.
My one concern is it's a bit old.  You'd think an app that used some of the new vector processing instructions could do a better job at heating up the cpu.

Answer (score 7):

I've had good luck with:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/null bs=1024
```

It keeps a single thread at 100% CPU. Run multiple times to keep more cores busy. Nice it if you want to.

Comment: +1 .. That is pretty clever I think.

Comment: Very nice usage of what's already on hand.

Comment: This may keep the CPU busy, but will it really stress it?  The various cpu stressing programs for windows seem to try a lot harder than just continually copying memory (maxed out SSE while driving the ALU and FPU).

Comment: @Caspin It's doing more than just copying memory, it's doing quite a bit of computation as well. Doing the same from /dev/zero results in MUCH higher rates than from /dev/urandom, and CPU barely twitches.

Comment: cpuburn is able to heat up the processor more quiekly as well as get it a few degrees hotter.  dd 57° C vs burnP6 60° C.

Comment: I finally attached a meter to my system to see which method causes the CPU to draw more power (more power == more heat).  The burn programs of course win.  The surprise is `ls / > /dev/null` draws nearly the same power as the urandom method.

Comment: @caspin Good to know!

Answer (score 0):

In conjunction with [sysadmin1138](https://serverfault.com/users/3038/sysadmin1138)'s [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/169071/artificially-burden-the-cpu/169076#169076), try adding one of the distributed computing tools like Stanford's Folding@Home (http://folding.stanford.edu)<sup>*</sup>.

<sub><sup>* I run f@h, and it generally keeps my laptop at 170-180F (I only run it when plugged-in, and not on my lap). I suspect it would would do similarly with a server CPU</sup></sub>

Comment: It's not obvious from my question, but I need this utility to do heat test on an embedded device.  While it's being cooked the only input is a serial line to verify the device is still alive.  Would f@h run on a machine with no internet access?

Comment: @Caspin, adding the "embedded" requirement definitely changes the scope of good answers :)